# Working with datatypes in swift

Tags: swift

I'm really new to swift and spent whole day trying to parse simple json, received thought websockets. Finally I got parsed (kinda), but many things still lay way beyond my understanding and I ask for some explanation.

Ok, here is what I have got so far

First of all I declare variable QUOTES, which will be Dictionary, same as in json

```
var QUOTES: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

I want my QUOTES var look like this at the end:

```
{
  "AAPL": {name: "Apple Comp", "price": 100},
  "F": {name: "Ford Comp", "price": 200}
}
```

When my websocket receives data, I want to populate QUOTES with received data.

```
socket.on("q"){data, ack in

        //data looks like this: [{q:[{c: "AAPL", price: 100}, {c: "F", price: 100}]}]


        //I convert first element of received [Any] to dictionary
        let object = data[0] as! Dictionary<String, NSArray>

        //I get array of quotes out of received data
        let quotes = object["q"] as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]

        //Now I want to iterate through received quotes to fill me QUOTES variable declared in the very beginning
        for quote in quotes {

            //I know ticker of current quote
            let ticker = quote["c"] as! String

            //Not sure if I have to do it - if QUOTES does not have current ticker in dictionary, I create it as empty dictionary

            if (QUOTES[ticker] == nil) {
                QUOTES[ticker] = [String: Any]()
            }


            //Now I iterate properties of received quote
            for(k,v) in quote {

                //And I want to fill my QUOTES dictionary,
                // but I get compile error
                //Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? 
                //I don't understand what compiler wants me to do?
                QUOTES[ticker][k] = v
            }
        }
    }
```

but I get compile error

> Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

I don't understand what compiler wants me to do?

Comment: Where is the question? If you are using Swift4, JSON parsing has been greatly simplified. For example, read http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/

Comment: question is the comments to the code, will substruct it to text